# Windows CMD findstr — поиск кириллических фраз в файлах с utf-8 кодировкой

Tags: windows, cmd

В cmd менял chcp 65001 не помогает, findstr находит только латинские слова.

```
findstr /s /i /n /a:0e /c:"искомоеслово" X:\path\*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Так задумано, findstr не поддерживает юникод, вместо можно использовать find:

```
C:\> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\> echo АБВГ >test.txt

C:\> find "Б" test.txt

---------- TEST.TXT
АБВГ
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).